# Error handling in spring reactor not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

I am not able to figure out why doOnError code is not getting executed even when tryDemo method is throwing NPE. I am trying to understand error handling in reactive programming and i am new to this

```
Mono.zip( Mono.fromCallable( ()->tryDemo()), Mono.fromCallable( ()-   >tryDemo1()),Mono.fromCallable(()-> tryDemo2() ))
        .flatMap( data -> Mono.just( Tuples.of( data.getT1(), data.getT2(),data.getT3() ) ) )
        .doOnError( e -> log.error( "Error {}", e.getStackTrace() ) )
        .subscribe(T->{log.info("Tuple {}",T.getT2()  );});



public Mono<String> tryDemo() {
    log.info( "Data--1" );

    return Mono.error( NullPointerException::new );
    //return Mono.just( "1" );
}

15:56:07.023 [main] INFO com.infosys.rtbm.Test - Data--1
15:56:07.027 [main] INFO com.infosys.rtbm.Test - Tuple MonoJust
```

Comment: Now if i try remove Mono.fromCallable and execute the method directly inside Mono.zip doOnError Method is getting executed but subscribe Method is not getting executedwhen i pass correct value insted of NPE in tryDemomethod

Answer (score 6):

## Don't forget to SUBSCRIBE me

In your example, you return `Mono` of error. The tricky part here is that `fromCallable` expects that you return a scalar value.

If we look at the API of `Mono.fromCallable`, we will find out that the accepted parameter is

```
public static <T> Mono<T> fromCallable(Callable<? extends T> supplier)
```

which means if our `Callable` returns `Mono`, we will get

```
Mono<Mono<Object>> monoOfMono = Mono.fromCallable(() -> 
     Mono.error(NullPointerException::new)
);
```

So, in case we need to produce an error, we have to throw that exception directly in the lambda

```
Mono<Object> justMono = Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
     throws new NullPointerException()
});
```

To Sumup, `Mono.fromCallable` does not try to check whether return type is a stream. Thus, your `Mono` is considered a normal scalar value and propagated downstream. So, to fix that you may do the following:

### Throws an exception in your `tryDemo` method:

```
Mono.zip( Mono.fromCallable( ()->tryDemo()), Mono.fromCallable( ()-   >tryDemo1()),Mono.fromCallable(()-> tryDemo2() ))
    .flatMap( data -> Mono.just( Tuples.of( data.getT1(), data.getT2(),data.getT3() ) ) )
    .doOnError( e -> log.error( "Error {}", e.getStackTrace() ) )
    .subscribe(T->{log.info("Tuple {}",T.getT2()  );});



public String tryDemo() {
    log.info( "Data--1" );

    throw new NullPointerException();
    //return "1";
}
```

### Replace `fromCallable` onto `defer`

You may achieve laziness, that you wanted to achieve with `fromCallable`, using the `Mono.defer` operator which in that case expected `Mono` as a return type from lambda.

If we look at the API of that operator we will observe the following

```
public static <T> Mono<T> defer(Supplier<? extends Mono<? extends T>> supplier);
```

in that case, we have `Supplier` which expects exactly `Mono` of something as a return type, so once you try your initial code again, you will achieve expected behavior:

```
Mono<Object> justMono = Mono.defer(() -> 
     Mono.error(NullPointerException::new)
);
```

In that case, once the supplier returns a `Mono`, `Mono.defere` subscribes to it and receive an error signal:

```
Mono.zip( 
        Mono.defer(() -> tryDemo()), 
        Mono.defer(() -> tryDemo1()),
        Mono.defer(() -> tryDemo2())
    )
    .flatMap(data -> Mono.just(Tuples.of( 
         data.getT1(), 
         data.getT2(), 
         data.getT3()
    )))
    .doOnError( e -> log.error( "Error {}", e.getStackTrace() ) )
    .subscribe(T -> {
        log.info("Tuple {}",T.getT2()  );
    });
```

Comment: Correct me if i am wronge. While using Mono.fromCallable method does it handle error by its self.How different is from Mono.defer.

Comment: `Mono.fromCallable` expect that your Callable<T> return an `Object`, so once you do that, it propagates it downstream. In your case, you return `Mono.error(() -> new NPE())`. So, where do you throw your exception, so it will cause an error caught by the `fromCallable` operator? In fact, your method produces just an object and if you try to add at the end `T.getT2() instanceof Mono` you will see `true`. In contrast, `Mono.defer`, expects the `Supplier<Mono<T>>`, so it will return T value, once subscribe to returned Mono from `Supplier`.